# How to set default value to asp textbox in radgrid while the texbox is data binded

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid

I have textbox code in .aspx file as below

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn  UniqueName="Format" HeaderText="Format" DataField="SystemMessageTextId" HeaderStyle-Width="60">
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFormat" Text='<%# Eval("Format") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFormat" Text='<%# Bind("Format") %>' MaxLength="255"></asp:TextBox>
                    <span style="color: Red">*&nbsp;
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfFormat" runat="server" ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid Format value." ControlToValidate="txtFormat" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </span>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

The .aspx.cs file looks like below

```
 if ((e.Item is GridEditableItem) && (e.Item.IsInEditMode))

 {
        GridEditableItem edititem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
       ((TextBox)(edititem["Format"].FindControl("txtFormat"))).Text = "pdf";
 }
```

I have this part in GridItemCreated function, but when I try it, the default value won't show. Can someone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Try the `ItemDataBound` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        TextBox txtFormat = (item.FindControl("txtFormat") as TextBox);
        txtFormat.Text = "Your text";
    }
}
```

If you want to assign/access data then its better to use ItemDataBound event.
Suppose you want assign textchanged event to Textbox then if we have to use ItemCreated event.

Answer (score 0):

Please put Text="0" in your textbox in the gridview to set default value 0.